# Multiple tables related to one, via one-to-to relationship. Best practice

Tags: mysql, sql, database, one-to-one

Let's say that we have 3 tables: student, professor and contact_info. Both student and professor have a one-to-one relationship to contact_info.
I could either have the tables arranged like

**student**

| id | contact_info_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |

**professor**

| id | contact_info_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |

**contact_info**

| id | phone | ... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | ... |
| 2 | 321 | ... |

**or**

**student**

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |

**professor**

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |

**contact_info**

| id | student_id | professor_id | phone | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | null | 123 | ... |
| 2 | null | 1 | 321 | ... |

I'm not fully convinced with either since I can see pros and cons for both. I tried unsuccessfully to find a duplicate for my question. Maybe someone can enlighten me with the best practices in this cases. Probably it'll end up with *depends*, but I'd like to hear it.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: the first option, definitely

Answer (score 0):

This formal design is easier if you use a Person entity to represent all those who have contact information. Students and Professors are all Persons.  It happens that those Persons have different roles. In fact, in a real-world uni, some Persons serve both roles (think graduate students leading undergraduate classes).

So maybe you have a Role table. Alice is a tenured professor. Burt is a fourth year year undergrad and also a teaching assistant. Carla is a first-year grad student. Elian is both a third year PhD candidate and an adjunct professor.  You get the idea.

Comment: the tables are just for reference. My question wasn't aimed to solved this particular problem of students and professors but rather a best practice solution. You can change professor for "shop" if it makes it easier to understand